# IF else in Panda based on dataframe column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe, I would like to either divide by 1 or by another dataframe column if the value of the dataframe is not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.where:

```
df['abc_new'] = np.where(df.abc.eq(0), df.xyz, df.xyz.div(df.abc))

timestamp       device  abc     xyz     abc_new
0   2019-11-08  device1 1000    2000    2.000000
1   2019-11-09  device1 2000    3000    1.500000
2   2019-11-10  device1 0       5000    5000.000000
3   2019-11-11  device1 0       5000    5000.000000
4   2019-11-12  device1 5000    2000    0.400000
5   2019-11-13  device1 6000    1000    0.166667
```

Or you can use:

```
df.xyz.div(df.abc.add(df.abc.eq(0)))
```

Comment: Hi Allen, Sorry I forgot to mention. I can't use numpy

Comment: Please see my udpate.